# Use scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.setdiag on only a part of a dok_matrix object

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Let's suppose I have a (very large) sparse matrix being a scipy.sparse.dok_matrix object. I want to set the diagonal of only a submatrix to certain value. I first thought something like this would work:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

dim = 20 # dim can go up to large numbers
A = sp.dok_matrix((num, num))
A[num//2:-1,num//2:-1].setdiag(2)
```

, but this only leads to an empty matrix (because of the way the matrix is internally stored using arrays, I suppose?). I know that for this small example I could use `setdiag` on the whole matrix and plug in an array with zeros at the beginning, but this won't be sufficent for larger matrix dimensions as the array would get too big.
I also tried:

```
A[num//2:-1,num//2:-1] = 2*sp.eye((num-1)//2)
```

This does what I want it to do, but much too slow. Is there a way to get to the same result faster (i.e. whithout setting all the entries of the submatrix explicitly)?

Comment: A `dok` is literally a dictionary (subclass).  Indexing of sparse matrices does not behave exactly like `ndarray` indexing.  In particular the distinction between views and copies does not apply.  Often when we want to do fancier or faster stuff with sparse matrices, we have to dig into the code, and understand how the data is actually stored and/or modified.

Comment: Instead of using the `setdiag` method, why not set the values directly, e.g. `A[np.arange(3), np.arange(3)] = np.arange(10,13)`?

Comment: I looked at `A._setdiag` - it just does `A[i,i] = v` for `i` in the shape of `A`.  That's the `base` method for sparse matrices.  So there's nothing special or fast about it.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for your comment, I wanted to avoid the use of numpy arrays because they cost a lot of memory (don't they?). But you are right, I probably overestimated the `setdiag` function a bit, thanks for the clarification.